# Giving color to the title in tableView in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, title, background-color

I am new to iPhone development. I want to change the colour of the title to brown. In default it is in gray colour. To display the title I am using the following method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Title";
}
```

I want to change the title backgound colour.

please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section`

Could be the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a UIView subclass that closely represents what is provided by default. Then change the color of your label. Then you can implement:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Which should return your custom view.